# UI Switch in Unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, material-design

I'm working on cross-platform mobile Unity application. I want add a switch on my screen allowing user turn on and off some functionality (like this: [Android Material Switch](https://material.io/guidelines/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch)).

As I know there is no native implementation of UI Switches in Unity. I found only this asset ([Switch UI element](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38257)) in Unity Asset Store, but it has really poor design.

So should I manually implement the Material Switch? Or is there anything in the web I can use in this case?

Thanks for response.

Comment: Is strictly nessesary to be a switch? Maybe a [Toggle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Toggle.html)?

Comment: May be u animation ui .. and switch it. ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use slider as switch.

Here are simple steps:

1. Create a slider by going to GameObject->UI->Slider
2. Check whole numbers chech-box in slider component's inspector.
3. set min value to 0 and max value to 1.
4. Use whatever graphics you want (even from material design)
5. Register "OnValueChange" method to handle change in value:

   ```
   public void SliderValueChanged(float value)
   {
       if(value == 0)
           // off
       else 
           // on
   }
   ```

Comment: I had the-same exact answer. I actually made a Switch component long time ago and was doing a full scan to see if I could find it on my computer before posting my answer then I saw this. Anyways, another thing OP must do is resize the width of the slider `RectTransform.sizeDelta.x`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably I'm a bit late, but for anyone who is viewing this question, I found a fairly good (free) Asset called [Lean GUI](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/lean-gui-72138#content) with switches and stuff.

Hope it'll help someone.